# List comprehension, invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I may be missing something obvious here, but why does the compiler raise 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' after the 'for' in the list comprehension?

```
num = str(2**1000)
print(num) 
sum = 0
print(sum[ int(num[i]) for i in range(len(num)) ])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a colon at the end? Also, `sum`, being a function, needs parentheses around its argument, i.e. the list you're generating via comprehension.

Comment: yes, like this:
print(sum([ int(num[i]) for i in range(len(num)) ]))
it do not cause any syntax errors anymore, but will raise a
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: It was previously a for loop. Problem solved.

Comment: Spoke too soon, after adding parenthesis I got quant's error but zhangxaochen's answer solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Here `sum = 0` you are rebinding a builtin function name to a variable name, which makes function call `sum(some_sequence)` invalid. Don't use any builtin type/function name as a custom variable name.

Besides, `sum[ ... ]` is invalid, use `sum(...)` instead because it's a function.

Comment: @Asad, the rebind raises a `TypeError`, and the `sum[...]` expression raises a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3):

You assigned `sum` to an integer `0`.

Next you are trying to access it as a list in your comprehension with `sum[...]` when you should really want to do `sum( )`.

In order to do *that* you need to get rid of `sum = 0`, because Python will not use the built-in method `sum()` and will instead do the equivalent of `0()` and raise another error.

You also don't need `for i in range(num)` because you can step through a string directly.

Putting all that together and you have:

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in num)))
```

*You also don't need the inner list.*

Or, the other more compact way:

```
print(sum(map(int, num)))
```

Comment: Thanks, will note all versions.